# Use Alias to or clause

Tags: sql

I have this subquery

```
 LEFT MERGE JOIN 
  (SELECT SOURCERECID,TAXITEMGROUP,TAXCODE,GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,VOUCHER,TAXAMOUNT,TAXAMOUNTCUR FROM ##TGJAE) TTRIVA ON TT.VOUCHER = TTRIVA.VOUCHER 
  AND TT.SOURCERECID = TTRIVA.SOURCERECID 
  AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRIVA.TAXITEMGROUP 
  AND (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RIVA%')
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%') 
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP') 
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPS25AP')                                           
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPS8AP')
  AND TTRIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

I want to know if its possible to apply alias to each `OR` clause like:

```
  AND (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RIVA%') AS RIVA
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%') AS RISR
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP') AS IEPSCUOTAP
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPS25AP') AS IEPS25AP                                      
  OR (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPS8AP') AS IEPS8AP
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: mmm... Aliases are for columns, not conditions.

Comment: but there is no way to implement that to name it and use into another part of query? @dotNET

Comment: No, you cant! And why do you want that anyways?

Comment: because into another part of query I call "TTRIVA.TAXCODE" but I can´t distinct what TTRIVA.TAXCODE I call it can be whatever of that 5 @JorgeCampos

Comment: I think you miss understood the concept of the OR in a query. It is just a boolean code. No matter where in the query you call this column, what matter is the final logical combination. You could rewrite that condition as `TTRIVA.TAXCODE like 'RIVA%' OR TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%' OR TTRIVA.TAXCODE IN ('IEPSCUOTAP','IEPS25AP','IEPS8AP')`

Comment: Also I think you are here in an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Try to explain WHAT you want to achieve not HOW you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Alias's are meant for providing temporary names for results, that are used only in that instance. Looks like you'd probably be best handling this off to an object to be manipulated.

Can you provide more input on why you would want to do this?

> I want to do this because into another part of query I call TTRIVA.TAXCODE but I can´t distinct what TTRIVA.TAXCODE I call it can be whatever of that 5

Based off this, it sounds like you're looking to return only 1 specific field of data, while grabbing multiple. This would be best done with an object, or in the system that is utilizing the information (or make separate queries).

There are also some issues with your conditions. I'd recommend using brackets where possible to make your desired result more clear.

Here is an example:

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT 
    SOURCERECID,
    TAXITEMGROUP,
    TAXCODE,
    GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
    VOUCHER,TAXAMOUNT,
    TAXAMOUNTCUR 
    FROM ##TGJAE) AS TTRIVA 
ON TT.VOUCHER = TTRIVA.VOUCHER 
    AND TT.SOURCERECID = TTRIVA.SOURCERECID 
    AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRIVA.TAXITEMGROUP 
    AND TTRIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
    AND (
        TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RIVA%'
        OR TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%'
        OR TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP'
        OR TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPS25AP'                                          
        OR TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPS8AP'
    )
```

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, this should work. If we look at the bottom section, you're going to be grabbing data for each of the taxcodes matching (RIVA%,RISR%, IEPSCUOTAP, IEPS25AP, and IEPS8AP). If you want only 1 of the tax codes, I'd recommend separate queries and only running them when required.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I want to do this because into another part of query I call `TTRIVA.TAXCODE` but I can´t distinct what `TTRIVA.TAXCODE` I call it can be whatever of that 5

Comment: With that in mind, these should be separate joins. They shouldn't all be lumped at the same time. Partition and re-sort your query. If you explain in detail what you're trying to accomplish, I can probably help write some of it :)

Comment: Updated the main answer. Used a longer notation than needed in order to help with the explanation. GL.